# Joomla Modal not on every page

Tags: joomla

I have a older Joomla intallation which includes a modal feature, however I have noticed in the sourcecode that the related JS and CSS only load on the main index page - it's not being loaded on all other pages.

Is there a way to include this globally ?

Some advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - by adding:

```
    <?php JHTML::_( 'behavior.modal' ); ?>
```